# Ubuntu 16.04 bootup very slow because of network service

Tags: networking, 16.04

My desktop have a boot slowed because of the Network service startup.
I think its a problem on the system because in the 15.10 it wasn't happen.

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.


graphical.target @1min 45.752s
└─multi-user.target @1min 45.752s
  └─core-daemon.service @1min 43.382s +2.370s
    └─network-online.target @1min 43.368s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 36.123s +7.245s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 33.019s +3.086s
          └─dbus.service @1min 32.383s
            └─basic.target @1min 32.350s
              └─sockets.target @1min 32.350s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 32.349s +583us
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 32.314s
                    └─apparmor.service @11.811s +2.118s
                      └─local-fs.target @11.792s
                        └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @2min 12.245s
                          └─run-user-1000.mount @2min 9.612s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @6.616s
                              └─systemd-remount-fs.service @6.503s +103ms
                                └─systemd-journald.socket @2.150s
                                  └─-.slice @2.133s
```

Some time the wireless interface cannot connect whit the AP and start a lot of retries until the wifi icon disappear of the menu bar.

Next the "systemd-analyze blame":

```
      7.349s dev-sda5.device
      7.245s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.086s NetworkManager.service
      3.055s apt-daily.service
      3.012s ModemManager.service
      2.494s accounts-daemon.service
      2.370s core-daemon.service
      2.236s warsaw.service
      2.206s gpu-manager.service
      2.125s grub-common.service
      2.118s apparmor.service
      1.851s systemd-udevd.service
      1.773s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.729s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.595s thermald.service
      1.226s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.181s ondemand.service
      1.173s polkitd.service
      1.172s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.167s speech-dispatcher.service
      1.135s cgroupfs-mount.service
      1.134s systemd-user-sessions.service
      1.130s pppd-dns.service
       962ms ebtables.service
       914ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c7ffeba8\x2d114f\x2d4d27\x2db46a\x2d678c5a943d6e.service
       907ms rsyslog.service
       894ms colord.service
       784ms systemd-logind.service
       714ms binfmt-support.service
       613ms systemd-journald.service
       604ms lightdm.service
       583ms avahi-daemon.service
       572ms wpa_supplicant.service
       539ms irqbalance.service
       518ms virtualbox.service
       464ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       429ms systemd-sysctl.service
       415ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       374ms apport.service
       370ms systemd-localed.service
       350ms upower.service
       346ms udisks2.service
       320ms systemd-rfkill.service
       304ms home.mount
       296ms console-setup.service
       295ms ufw.service
       288ms systemd-hostnamed.service
       285ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       280ms systemd-random-seed.service
       239ms dns-clean.service
       236ms networking.service
       208ms dev-hugepages.mount
       207ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       206ms dev-mqueue.mount
       201ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       196ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
       195ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       174ms quagga.service
       163ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       145ms plymouth-read-write.service
       132ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       118ms rtkit-daemon.service
       103ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        99ms user@1000.service
        94ms sysstat.service
        79ms resolvconf.service
        69ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
        32ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        17ms plymouth-start.service
        16ms docker.socket
        14ms alsa-restore.service
         6ms rc-local.service
         5ms ureadahead-stop.service
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl1.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       583us snapd.socket
```

Comment: Theres a serious problem with network in ubuntu 16.04. I saw a lot of problems in a web involving networks in this version. My notebook can't stabilish a wifi connection and some times I need to reboot a lot of time until I can connect to AP